# Regularity of Cramer-Rao inequality for unbiased estimators

Tags: integration, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, regularization

As I understand it, the use of Cramer-Rao inequality requires a few regularity conditions, including **the parametric family being dominated** and **swapping of differentiation and integration in computation of expectation of the estimator**. How do I prove **the latter condition for unbiased estimators**?

> Mathematically, suppose $\hat{\theta}\left(X\right)$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$. I want the proof of the following statement
>   $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\int \hat{\theta}\left(X\right)p(x,\theta)dx = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \left(\hat{\theta}\left(X\right)p(x,\theta)\right)dx$$

My progress : Obviously, $\hat{\theta}\left(X\right)$ being unbiased for $\theta$, the left hand side is $1$. I'm having trouble showing that the right hand side is also equal to $1$. I have tried to right $p(x,\theta)$ in terms of the log-likelihood $L(x,\theta)$ as $e^{L(x,\theta)}$ without success. My calculations reduce to showing that $E_{\theta}\left(\hat{\theta}\left(X\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}L(X,\theta)\right)=1$.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the statement:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\int \hat{\theta}\left(X\right)p(x,\theta)dx = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \left(\hat{\theta}\left(X\right)p(x,\theta)\right)dx$$

Is true in general. For example, letting $P[x|\theta] \sim \textrm{Exp}(\lambda)$, then $\hat{\lambda}(X) = \lambda$ is an unbiased oracle estimator.

We then have that"

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\int \hat{\lambda}\left(X\right)p(x,\lambda)dx =
\int \frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\left(\hat{\lambda}\left(X\right)p(x,\lambda)\right)dx\\
& \Leftrightarrow 1 = \int\frac{d}{d\lambda}\lambda^2\textrm{Exp}(\lambda x)  = \int 2\lambda\textrm{Exp}(\lambda x) + \lambda^2x\textrm{Exp}(\lambda x) dx) = 2 + \lambda^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The wikipedia page doesn't mention that unbiasedness is a requirement, but does incorporate how they use it in one of the formulations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Multivariate_case). The following section mentions exchanging differentiation and integration, but mentions two sufficient methods for showing it can be done.